# Python : selenium find element angular

Tags: python, angular, selenium, web-scraping, findelement

[printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94hup.png)

I tried to read this line, but it doesn't work :

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[contains(@_ngcontent-whw-c159 data-cy,'hotel-title')]")
print(element.text)
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: Try with just data-cy.

Comment: no it's the same 'Message: Unable to locate element: //span[contains(@data-cy,'hotel-title')]'

Comment: Blank or errors>?

Comment: I get this message : exception unhandled 'Message: Unable to locate element: //span[contains(@data-cy,'hotel-title')]
Stacktrace:
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:181:5'

Comment: Also it's h1 not span.

Comment: no always the same : "Unable to locate element"

Comment: Now check if it's under any iframes or shadowroots.

Comment: No, I don't think

Comment: Is it a public url so I can check.

Comment: Yes here : https://booking.luxairtours.lu/?lang=fr&adults=2&children=0&childages=0&sortBy=TotalPrice&sortOrder=desc&departuredate=2022-07-01&returndate=2022-07-17&themes=Custom6&durationstart=5&durationend=8
I would like to get the names of the hotels to make a list

Comment: You didn't wait for the elements to pop up which might have been the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hotel_names=[x.text for x in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//h1[@class='title']")]
```

To get all the names on that page you can grab all h1 with class title.

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,10)                                 

driver.get("https://booking.luxairtours.lu/?lang=fr&adults=2&children=0&childages=0&sortBy=TotalPrice&sortOrder=desc&departuredate=2022-07-01&returndate=2022-07-17&themes=Custom6&durationstart=5&durationend=8")
hotel_names=[x.text for x in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//h1[@class='title']")))]
print(hotel_names)
```

To make sure it loads use webdriver waits for the elements to appear.

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Outputs:

```
['LUXiClub Atlantica Aegean Blue Resort', 'LUXiClub Grecotel Marine Palace & Aqua Park', 'LUXiClub Insotel Punta Prima Resort & Spa', 'LUXiClub Sol Nessebar Palace', 'LUXiClub Grifid Club Hotel Bolero', 'LUXiClub Paloma Grida', 'LUXiClub Akassia Swiss Resort', 'LUXiClub Sol Nessebar Resort', 'LUXiClub Grand Hotel Holiday Resort', 'LUXiClub Relaxia Lanzasur Club']
```